# Where can i obtain symbols table for JavaService?

Tags: java, jboss, java-service-wrapper

I have a crash dump (Windows) for JavaService (it's basically a wrapper to expose JBoss app server as a service).

I see this error on opening the dump file using windbg :

```
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.
```

Where can i find the symbols table file?

Answer (score 0):

Please send your crash dump along with your wrapper.conf and wrapper.log files to Tanuki Software support at support@tanukisoftware.com  We would be happy to look into the problem for you.

Cheers,
Leif